# Creating a JAR archive without Java/OpenJDK

Tags: java, docker, jar

Is there a simple binary or a package, that I can use without the whole openjdk just to archive some folders and files into a JAR archive?

Basically I have to create an jar-archive of non-java files, in a docker container.

I thought there must be something like

```
FROM simple-jar
jar cf archive.jar ./some-folder
```

Comment: Jar files are just zip files.  You can use any zip archive library.

Comment: Cool, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @markspace to explaining that `.jar` files are basically `.zip` files.

I've used the `kramos/alpine-zip` to zip a folder to later copy it into my build.

My Dockerfile looked something like this

```
FROM kramos/alpine-zip as zipper

COPY ./data  /data
RUN zip /archive.jar -r /data

# Build project
FROM other/etc

COPY --from=zipper /archive.jar 
...
```